# QuickBlox Account User, API users and API application

Tags: ios, quickblox

I'm having a little confusion among these three.

Is `account user` the account with which I sign up QuickBlox as developer?

Is `API users` the end users?

What's `API application`? Do I create one by signing onto the QuickBlox web interface and create one there, and then use that to create the session in `[QBAuth createSessionWithExtendedRequest:extendedAuthRequest delegate:self]`?

Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is account user the account with which I sign up QuickBlox as
>   developer?

Yes, it's Admin panel account

> Is API users the end users?

Yes, it's your mobile application user

BTW, account user is also API user, you can use account user to login to your mobile app

> What's API application? Do I create one by signing onto the QuickBlox
>   web interface and create one there,

Yes, you are right